# if exist !SOMEPATH! not working in batch file

Tags: batch

I have a batch script in which i am using multiple if exist statement, the problem is all statements are working except one .

Following variables are set

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET basedrive=E:
SET tfworkspace=!basedrive!\TFS
SET envdefault=%1
SET projenv=!envdefault!
echo subapp=!subapp! subappservice=!subappservice! 
SET tfworkspacepath=!tfworkspace!\!releasebranch!\!app!\!subapp!
```

This statement works,

```
if exist "!tfworkspacepath!" (robocopy "!tfworkspacepath!"\sourcecode\messagebroker\ /E /NFL /NJS /NDL /ETA  "!basedir!\!messagebroker!" )  else SET /a foldererror=1
SET tfworkspacepathservice=!tfworkspace!\!releasebranch!\!app!\!subapp!\sourcecode\build\!projenv!
```

This statement doesn't work, by does not work i mean even thou the path does not exist it it still tries to robocopy.

```
if exist !tfworkspacepathservice! (
  robocopy !tfworkspacepathservice! /E /NFL /NJS /NDL /ETA  "!basedir!\!scripts!") else  SET /a foldererror =!foldererror!+1
```

I am new to batch writing, please guide me

Comment: Welcome to batch scripting, aka hell. Can you switch to a modern scripting language like PowerShell? Makes things so much easier.

Comment: @Mark business limitation is to use batch, otherwise i can moderately code this stuff well in vbs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all my apologies to everyone who came here trying to help.

what was wrong ?

i had an if statement which verifies a subappservice variable if it is empty, syntax wise it was imperfect.see the BAD syntax below

```
if NOT !subappservice!=="" (SET scripts=!scripts!\!subapp!) else SET projenv=!projenv!\!subappservice!& SET scripts=!scripts!\!subapp!\!subappservice!
```

i corrected it to below to fix the problem

```
if [!subappservice!]== []  (SET scripts=!scripts!\!subapp!) else SET projenv=!projenv!\!subappservice!& SET scripts=!scripts!\!subapp!\!subappservice!
```

my take - even thou syntax was bad or imperfect CMD.exe does not issue any warning and i kept on validating my script until i found this accidently. i am putting it here so that someone else can benefit from my mistake :)